# How to use complex layout in grid row

Tags: android, layout, layout-inflater

I have the following code in resultlookup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/layoutResultOuter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtResultLeadCode"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ID" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtResultFirstName"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:singleLine="true"  android:text="First Name" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtResultspace"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text=" " />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtResultLastName"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:singleLine="true" android:text="Last Name" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I want this layout to be used in a grid view, as 1 of it's row. The grid is a single column grid.

The data is stored in SQLite DB, I retrieve the data and have to display it in the grid format.

Read some where that I can use "View Inflater" or "Layout Inflater". If there is any sample code, please let me know.

I want some thing like this:

[image: resultant image]

Comment: Issue Resolved... 
Used the following code in "Adapter" class
`LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutResultOuter);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
                   (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View hiddenInfo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultleadlookup, myLayout, false);
            addView(hiddenInfo);`

Comment: Also used the <include/> in XML file. Thanks to @Ghost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use the `<include>` tag. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) how you do it.

Comment: I am filling the grid dynamically. This one's right in the XML

Comment: Yeah.. But then, you hadn't mentioned about dynamic filling of your view.

Comment: `LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutResultOuter);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
                   (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View hiddenInfo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.resultleadlookup, myLayout, false);
            addView(hiddenInfo);`
in grid Adapter

Comment: The link is now broken. That's why you should always include the answer in the answer.  External links should be supplemental and the answer should be able to stand on its own.

Answer (score 0):

By using custom adapter you can use your own layout for populating items in the GridView.

use above layout as the item and inflate it in getView() method it will work properly..

check this once  : [custom adapter for grid view](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)